# ¿ cómo realizar una consulta a mysql mediante funcion php?

Tags: php, select

Deseo tener una funcion que consulta a toda una tabla de mysql.
esta función devuelve los resultados del SELECT.
Pero estos resultados yo debo poder acomodarlos según yo prefiera. aveces solo nombre, aveces solo Edad, etc o todos todos los registros.

algo así pero mediante funcion:

```
    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'xxx', 'database');
$personas= (mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM personas"));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($personas)) {
    echo $row['nombres'];
    echo $row['apellidos'];
    echo $row['x'];
    echo $row['y'];
    echo $row['n'];
}
```

Comment: Y la pregunta o error es...?

Comment: ¿Acomodarlos o seleccionar que columnas deseas mostrar?

Comment: Y la pregunta o error es...? – Paulo Urbano Rivera:
es una pregunta.
el punto es tener una sola funcion para hacer una consulta a una  tabla X de mysl. Y a esta función  lo pueda llamar desde cualquier parte. pero en algunas partes solo necesitaré mostrar un campo en otras varios campos y en otras todos los campos de la tabla mysql.

Comment: ¿Acomodarlos o seleccionar que columnas deseas mostrar?
En mi precaria manera de pensar. yo creo que la consulta  lo debe hacer a todos los campos de la tabla X de mysql (*). Pero al mostrarlos yo debo poder elejir que campos deseo mostrar. ya que es una sola función par ser utilizada en diferentes partes del sistema.

Comment: @Adesmirozeladaescobedo es que simplemente puedes enviar el nombre de la tabla como parámetro hacia una única función trayendo todos los campos; después de recibir el resultado, tú vas filtrando que campos mostrarle a un usuario o no. Eso es totalmente manejable ;)

Comment: Paulo Urbano Rivera: ese el detalle que como hago para que me retorne los campos de la tabla. quizas en un array, y como los muestro en la vista como una tabla de bootstrap.